# C# Taking the html code of introduction site rather than the actual one, how to skip this?

Tags: c#, html, redirect

I have the following problem. My C# application makes use of a webrequest and reades the html code of a url in order to do a bunch of things later on. While everything works fine, there are some websites that when visited they redirect you to another website (http://something.com/disclamer) for example and after you click yes you go back to the original website.

When I run my app it always only checks the html code of the disclaimer page and never gets to the actual page I asked for. I cannot really find a solution at this point since I can't find anything useful in the short html code of the disclaimer site (that comes before the one I want to check).

Any ideas on how I can skip that and take the code for the website I am actually interested in? Please note that I can't find any html redirection code indication (META HTTP-EQUIV etc) in any of the two websites.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can check the StatusCode to decide if you have been redirected.  Status codes of 30x will tell you that you've been redirected, in which case you'll need to follow the link in the redirect.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode.aspx

Comment: It's not that kind of redirection I am afraid. By clicking the 'yes' button you fire a <button onclick="__doPostBack towards the server. Any way I can work around that?

Comment: If you're trying to implement a webcrawler that takes care of all client-side hacks and edge cases you are setting yourself up for disappointment.   Look at how google crawls your pages; it largely makes do with status codes and http get.  Anything else... all bets are off.  If you could make clearer what the 'bunch of other stuff' it is you want to do, you might find another solution may be appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to analyse the HTML code of such a page with a disclaimer to know which method is used there to make a redirect. Each case can be different: it can be either client-side or server-side redirection. If this disclaimer button submits a form, you will need to make a POST request imitating a button click.

Comment: It's exactly that, you fire a <button onclick="__doPostBack blah blah. If I get right what you are suggesting:
1) read the html code and search for "<button onclick="__doPostBack" in order to identify if the page is a landing page or not
2) if found, read the unique ids of the postback (using substrings?) and then make a similar post request to the server?

Is that right? if yes, could you provide sample code?